# airflow dag while parsing actually running the sql against the DB

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

hellow airflow gurus,
we have a very weird phenomenon in our dag in airflow:
every min_file_process_interval - in our case 120 seconds, as airflow processes the dag files, it validates the queries within against our snowflake DB. this causes a lot of costs as it consumes credits.
we are looking for a way to prevent it from validating the sql within the dag.
been sitting on it for days, still no success. we dont want to make min_file_process_interval longer as this is not the direction.

what we defenately see is that the hook object is causing this behaviour for some reason.
Thanks for your help.

i add here the dag code :

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.providers.snowflake.operators.snowflake import SnowflakeOperator
from airflow.providers.snowflake.hooks.snowflake import SnowflakeHook
from airflow.utils.task_group import TaskGroup
from datetime import datetime

# Define the DAG
default_args = {
    'owner': 'Asaf',
    'depends_on_past': False,
    'start_date': datetime(2023, 10, 1),
    'retries': 0,
}

dag = DAG(
    'Asaf_MNG_DAG_master_general',
    default_args=default_args,
    schedule_interval=None,
    catchup=False,
)

with dag:

    with TaskGroup("load_mng_manual_tables_to_stg") as load_mng_manual_tables_to_stg:

        hook = SnowflakeHook(snowflake_conn_id='AIRFLOW_CONN_SNOWFLAKE_DEFAULT')

        # Get the list of queries from the database
        sql_query = "SELECT QUERY FROM SANDBOX.PUBLIC.MNG_PARALLEL_AIRFLOW"
        queries_group = hook.get_records(sql_query)

        if queries_group:
            queries_group = [row[0] for row in queries_group]
            queries_group = ";".join(queries_group).split(';')
        
            # Create dynamic tasks for each query
            for idx, query in enumerate(queries_group):
                task = SnowflakeOperator(
                    task_id=f"query_{idx}",
                    sql=query,
                    snowflake_conn_id='AIRFLOW_CONN_SNOWFLAKE_DEFAULT',
                    autocommit=True,
                )
```

tries to create a dynamic dag creating tasks running SF queries

Comment: All the top-level code (that is not a task body) is executed every time dag parsing occurs. This is explicitly described as a not scalable design pattern in the [docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/best-practices.html): *Specifically you should not run any database access, heavy computations and networking operations.* Use dynamic task mapping instead

Answer (score 1):

Airflow isn't validating the queries, instead, it's having to run the query to generate the task group. You are correct, though, this is not an ideal design pattern for a DAG.

I'm not sure how large the data is that's used to generate this task group, but there are some options, depending on your use case.

- Use DynamicTaskMapping (Airflow 2.3+). Docs [here](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/authoring-and-scheduling/dynamic-task-mapping.html#mapping-with-non-taskflow-operators). This is likely going to need the `.expand_kwargs` method.
- Create a DAG that writes the data from `SELECT QUERY FROM SANDBOX.PUBLIC.MNG_PARALLEL_AIRFLOW` to an Airflow Variable, then instead of using a SnowflakeHook to generate the tasks you can use an Airflow variable call with `Variable.get()`. This will also make a call to a metaDB, but uses the AirflowDB instead of Snowflake.
- Put this information inside of a file (csv or json) that lives in the container and parse the file, this is the fastest solution since no external db calls are needed.

Comment: thanks rafa !
so you say this is an intented behaviour - by design of airflow ? 
it actully runs the queries every time it parses the file ?

Comment: When a DAG file is parsed all top level code is run, so if there is a query in the top level, then yes it will be run every time the DAG is parsed which could be hundreds of times per hour.